# Send a single HTTP request with JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am creating a test plan with JMeter and i am having problems.

The question is i want to send a single HTTP request to, let's say, setup the system ... and later i would send full attack for load test. But i need this previous single POST request in order to set the proper condition in the system.

Is this possible with JMeter 2.12?

P.D. I think the question is fully explained but for some reson it seems not comply to S.O. style code ... let's put some additional text to see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible. I would use **setUp Thread Group** in JMeter to do any necessary setup for my load test. Samplers inside the  'setUp Thread Group' will get executed first in the test plan.

- Add 'setUp Thread Group' under 'Test Plan' - Let the thread count and loop count be 1
- Add the single HTTP request which does the setup
- Add all other HTTP requests under the regular Thread Group